# How can we execute multiple sp's one after another in T-SQL?

Tags: t-sql

I have multiple sp's which I need to run for different days multiple times a day.

Rather than executing manually every single sp individually, is there any way we can run/execute those sp's one after another (means once one sp is executed then another one starts and then another)?

Answer (score 0):

Create a procedure and inside that procedure add a time when you want to call another procedure for example

```
create procedure xyz
 as
begin
    set nocount on;
    --  For executing the stored procedure at 09:00 A.M
    declare @setTime nvarchar(50)
    set @setTime = '09:00'

    while 1 = 1
    begin
        waitfor time @setTime 
        begin
            --the procedure which you want to call at specific time interval
            execute [dbo].[StoredProcedureName];
        end
    end
END
```

And Now you can schedule that store procedure in SQl server thorough Jobs (SQL server Agent) like you main Stored procedure runs daily at 08:00AM in the morning and the rest SP's will follow so on and so forth ..